# react-native-svg - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent'

Tags: react-native, npm, webpack, react-native-web, react-native-svg

I am using `"react-native-web-linear-gradient": "^1.1.2",` which requires `react-native-svg`. I am using version `^13.8.0` for the svg package.

When I run `yarn storybook`, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/NativeComponent/NativeComponentRegistry' in '<project-root>/node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/module/fabric'
    at <project-root>/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2016:28
```

Answer (score 1):

I found on the `react-native-svg` issues page on Github [this comment](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/issues/1106) about upgrading from `9.8.5` to `9.8.6` broke their web build:

```
I'm using react-native-svg in a project with react-native and react-native-web. When upgrading from 9.8.5 to 9.8.6 (or later) the web build starts breaking with the following error:


./node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/module/elements/Image.js
Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native'.

It seems to me like the web compatibility layer is not used anymore, since it should not be loading that file for web at all.
```

So I downgraded my svg package to `9.8.5` and now it runs.

```
 "react-native-svg": "9.8.5",
```